# How to display Current Sharepoint site name in a script editor web part using JS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jsom

One of the Projects I am working on, I have to display SharePoint site name on a SharePoint library default edit form, I am using below code from tech net but it does not work, can someone please help me out to correct this and make it to work.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetSiteName");

function GetSiteName(){
  var SiteName = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderSiteName_onetidProjectPropertyTitle').innerHTML;//get the ID from 'view source' page
document.getElementById('lblsitename').innerHTML = SiteName;
}
</script>
<html>
<label id="lblsitename"></label>
</html></div>
```

I am dynamically trying to display the site name on a share point library upload (default edit form) so users get to see what site they are working on and this has to be dynamic in nature which is why I am using JSOM approach.

FYI, I am working with SharePoint online. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_spPageContextInfo.webTitle` to get current site title.

```
document.getElementById('lblsitename').innerHTML = _spPageContextInfo.webTitle;
```